# Use puppet or chef to config two db servers (HA) on AWS

Tags: automation, amazon-web-services, chef-infra, high-availability, puppet

How to use puppet or chef to config multi-servers?

For example, 
We need two servers to construct HA sql.

Server A need Server B's IP and username and password.
Server B also need Server A's IP and username and password.

But IPs are automatic generated by AWS.
And password are also randomly generated using puppet or chef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to approach this is to wire chef or puppet to CloudFormation, an AWS service that allows the programmatic creation of stacks. A full answer to this question would be a full-time consulting gig, but here are some resources to get you started:

[CFN with Puppet.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/IntegratingAWSCloudFormationWithPuppet.pdf)

[CFN with Chef.](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/IntegratingAWSCloudFormationWithOpscodeChef.pdf)

[CFN docs.](http://aws.amazon.com/documentation/cloudformation/)

Alternatively, you could approach this problem from the other side, configuring the EC2 instances from within [Chef](http://www.agileweboperations.com/amazon-ec2-instances-with-opscode-chef-using-knife) or [Puppet.](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/cloud_pack_getting_started.html)

Comment: Thanks, but is there other way to solve this problem using pure chef/puppet?

Comment: @ken.chen Added some links about configuring EC2 instances using pure chef/puppet